# Ansible stuck with local_action or delegate_to

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm running playbooks for years but now i'm facing a new issue without any clue, when I launch playbook against remote machine : it's ok for gathering facts and tasks. But then when I try a `delegate_to:` or `local_action` I face this error :

```
fatal: [test.local -> localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: No first item, sequence was empty.. No first item, sequence was empty.. No first item, sequence was empty.. No first item, sequence was empty.
```

I tried several little changes (switch to delegate_to, removing register etc...) but always the same error. I can't see what is the "item" and sequence I'm missing there... maybe in the inventory ? Even with `-vvvv` there not much details about the error.

The code is :

```
- name: test local action                                                                                                                                              
  local_action: ansible.builtin.command uptime 
  register: test                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                       
- name: debug                                                                                                                                                          
  debug:                                                                                                                                                               
    msg: "{{ test.stdout }}"
```

Any clue about how to fix it ?

Comment: working fine here. The problem must be outside of that playbook.

Comment: Yes sure, but the question is : where to look at ? There must be something ansible is looking for (variable related to localhost I guess) but is the error output does not permit to point it out... That's why I'm asking, someone should know what I'm missing there.

Comment: Your ansible config? Your inventory? You are not providing enough information.

Comment: Faulty var have been found ! Find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : Missing variable on group_vars produce this error.

Tasks with 'delegate_to' manage to find variables values in inventory/group_vars/all.yml. I've deducted this behaviour looking for the "first" filter. Luckily I haven't got so much things in my inventory. To conclude:  even if the machine is a "delegate_to machine" and in inventory it does not seems to find the group which it belongs the variable needs to be defined. To solve it without removing I used the default filter to set it.